# Neovim window rolls up when dividing screen horizontally with tmux

Tags: neovim, tmux

When I'm coding, I like to have neovim window up and command line window down to run my code on the screen. When I save a neovim file and divide the screen into two horizontally using tmux, the neovim window rolls up automatically instead of staying still. This doesn't happen when using vim with tmux, so I thought some specific configuration in `init.vim` file that is used only for neovim was causing this behavior, but I couldn't find any configuration that leads to this. I even removed the `init.vim` file to see if that solves this, but neovim window still rolled up automatically when I divided the screen, which means some specific default configuration for neovim is causing this behavior. I'm using neovim version 0.4.3 with tmux version 3.1b.

Comment: Do you mean the text scrolls up when the tmux pane is resized? Does it have something to do with the cursor position? NeoVim is scrolling the buffer so that the text under the cursor will stay displayed in the smaller screen space it has? Is that possibly the case? There's also `'scrolloff'`, try `:set scrolloff=0` and see if that makes a difference. You can also check `:verbose set scrolloff?` in both NeoVim and Vim to see if there's a difference there...

Comment: The text scrolls up when I divide the tmux pane horizontally into two. It has nothing to do with the cursor position. `scrolloff` had no effect and `scrolling` is an unknown option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using neovim but, if it can help, you can use the built-in terminal.

in exemple:

```
:split term://bash
```

Will open the terminal (with the bash shell) in the bottom.

You can get more information about the usage with `:help terminal-input` and there  is also a tutorial [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/neovim-terminal/) if you want